# Can I use criteria from any current form in a single query in Access 2003

Tags: ms-access

I have a report (ReportX) that I wish to open from two different forms (FormA and FormB) in my database.  I wish to do this because FormA and FormB address different aspects of my data, even if they ultimately get to the same output.  ReportX is based on data from QueryX.

The problem I have is that QueryX would ideally filter the data based on the current RecordID in the current form.  But I don't know how to accomplish this.  I'd like to design QueryX so that the criteria for RecordID is essentially CurrentForm!RecordID, but research suggests that I cannot do this.  Must I make separate but otherwise identical queries and reports for each form?  Or is there a way to use VBA to define the query criteria when I click on the OpenReportX command button?

I already tried using the WHERE condition in the OpenReport command:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportX", acViewPreview, ,"RecordID = " & RecordID
```

but that did not display the results I wished.  I need the report header to display/print for each RecordID and the page count in the page footer to reflect only the current/total pages of the RecordID in question.  (In other words, if record 1 is one page, record 2 is two pages and record 3 is three pages, then ReportX, when displaying the first page of record 2, should say "Page 1 of 2" and not "Page 2 of 6.")  So being able to display and print a single record properly using record filters would also solve my problem.

Which is the least cumbersome/most possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using the WHERE condition argument when you open a report:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptName", acViewPreview, ,"RecordID = " & Me!RecordID
```

In the case where a I need more control over a Report's recordsource than what the Where condition argument can do for me, I will set the Reports RecordSource to be blank (after designing the report). Next I write code create the correct SQL statement in the Open Report button's Click event, followed by code to open the report and pass in the SQL as an opening argument for the report.

```vb
Private Sub cmdOpenReport_Click()
    Dim sSQL as string
    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblWhatever WHERE RecordID = " & Me!RecordID
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptReportName", acViewPreview, , , ,sSQL
End Sub
```

Then in the report's Open event I write code to set the recordsource:

```vb
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) = False Then
        Me.RecordSource = Me.OpenArgs
    End If
End Sub
```

If neither of those accomplish what you want then you have an issue of a different sort. It's a little difficult for me to understand why you need All Records to show up in the header but only one record in the detail area. And how you expect to accomplish this. You might be best off trying to write a query first that gives you the exact results that your looking for so you know that it can be done.

As a side note, I actually use very few saved queries in my designs. It's not that there's anything wrong with using them, as the option is there for your convenience. I frequently use raw SQL on both forms and reports and set the RecordSource to the SQL on the Form or Reports Open or Load events.

Comment: Great!  I'd already tried the WHERE condition argument without success, but the OpenArgs property was exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can point to form data items in a query, and subsequently use that query in a report.  The forms need to be open before the report runs.  As far as having a header for each record, that is controlled in the settings of the report and how it displays the data.

In the Field, or Critera you can use the format:

```
[Forms]![frm_Process_Candidates]![QuestionTemplate]
```

Where frm_Process_Candidates would be the name assigned to your form, and QuestionTemplate is either the name of a control on your form, or a field from the data source of your form.

If you have a sub-form, there will be another [Form] call in the middle there.

```
[Forms]![frm_Dropdown_Admin]![frm_Dropdown_Admin_Detail].[Form]![text22]
```

Access should figure it out from there.

Comment: I do know how to point to **one** field in **one** form in a query.  But what I would like to do is more like: [Forms]![Whichever form is currently open whether it is FormA or FormB]![RecordID] - if that makes sense.

Comment: Pulling the data from the form will pull the current record, or in the case of a multi-record view, will pull the record flagged as active.  For dynamic form selection and record picking, you likely want to head into VBA land and either construnct your dataset there or have a custom function that returns what you want to your query.